# javascript replace string continueable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a code that replaces a string. Here is my HTML created by my PHP code.

```
...
foreach ($notes as $note) {
                echo '<li><input name="noteTypeID" type="radio" class="noteTypeID" value="'.$note['NOTETYPEID'].'"></li>';
            }
...
foreach (...) { 
...
    echo '<li class="getshrtcode">[srms_more_info id="'.$cnt.'" instanceID="'.$val_id.'" type="'.$val_type.'" noteCodeID="" planID=""]</li>';                               
...
                }
```

my script is like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var noteTypeID = null;
    var planID = null;
    jQuery('.noteTypeID').click(function() {
        noteTypeID = jQuery(this).val();
        planID = prompt("Enter a Template planID value from axcelerate");

        jQuery('.getshrtcode').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace('noteCodeID=""', 'noteCodeID="'+ noteTypeID +'"'));
            jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace('planID=""', 'planID="'+ planID +'"'));
        });

    });

});
```

the 1st change is fine but the next is not. I see that it can't re assign the `.getshrtcode` text because the `planID` and `noteCodeID` string have value. Is it possible to turn it `noteCodeID="" planID=""` again?

Comment: "Here is my HTML created by my PHP code." => that is your php

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a non-DOM entity with jquery which is not possible. When you have a template engine to generate HTML, the template code gets executed and gives results before any javascript loads, so you cannot set template properties unless the template engine itself provides you a mechanism to do this.

If you really want the customer to specify a certain template plan ID to present him with something specific, you need to load your page through an AJAX call where you send a request to the server passing `noteCodeID & planID` and respond with the desired HTML that comes as a result of the custom template engine execution.

If you have custom attributes in your HTML that you want to set using jquery, then you can simply use `attr` function :

```
$('#foobar').attr('foo','bar');
```